# Omnet++ and veins: assert fail: omnetTimestep == serverTimestep

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to run a minimal project using veins 4.4 in omnet++ 5.0. Using this guide: https://github.com/burtonwilliamt/carlogicapi/tree/master/tutorials/VeinsTutorial I manage to get their example running.

I then proceeded to make my own (very similar) version with my own (very simple) sumo net. But when I run this project I get the error:

```
<!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) CircleScenario.manager (id=6) at event #2, t=0.1: ASSERT: condition omnetTimestep == serverTimestep false in function processSimSubscription, veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc line 724.
```

Does anybody know why this error might occur?

There is no custom C++ code in this project, only the omnetpp.ini, the sumo xml-files and a scenario.

Scenario:

```
package circle;

import org.car2x.veins.nodes.Scenario;

network CircleScenario extends Scenario
{
    //inherited from Scenario
    connections allowunconnected:
}
```

omnetpp.ini:

```
[General]
cmdenv-express-mode = true
cmdenv-autoflush = true
cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s
#ned-path = ..
debug-on-errors = true

network = circle.CircleScenario  # the package where the Scenario is

##### Simulation Parameters ######
# * means TutorialScenario at the begginning
#sim-time-limit = 1000s
#tkenv-image-path = path/to/background/image.png
*.playgroundSizeX = 1000m
*.playgroundSizeY = 1000m
*.playgroundSizeZ = 50m

##### TraCIScenarioManager Parameters ######
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = false
*.manager.moduleType = "org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car"
*.manager.moduleName = "node"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = ""
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("circle.launchd.xml")

##### IEEE 802.11p Wireless Parameters #######
*.connectionManager.pMax = 20mW
*.connectionManager.sat = -89dBm
*.connectionManager.alpha = 2.0
*.connectionManager.carrierFrequency = 5.890e9 Hz
*.connectionManager.sendDirect = true

*.node[*].nicType = "Nic80211p"

*.**.nic.mac1609_4.txPower = 20mW
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 18Mbps

*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
*.**.nic.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true
*.**.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm
*.**.nic.phy80211p.usePropagationDelay = true

##### Car Parameters #####
# Application Parameters

# Mobility Parameters
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType =                 
"org.car2x.veins.modules.mobility.traci.TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].veinsmobility.x = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.y = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.z = 0

**.debug = true
**.coreDebug = true
```

Edit: sumo files:

circle.edg.xml:

```
<!-- filename: circle.edg.xml -->
<edges>
  <edge from="1" id="1to2" to="2" />
  <edge from="2" id="2to3" to="3" />
  <edge from="3" id="3to4" to="4" />
  <edge from="4" id="out" to="5" />
</edges>
```

circle.launchd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- debug config -->
<launch>
    <copy file="circle.net.xml" />
    <copy file="circle.rou.xml" />
    <copy file="circle.settings.xml" />
    <copy file="circle.sumo.cfg" type="config" />
</launch>
```

circle.nod.xml

```
<!-- filename: circle.nod.xml -->
<nodes>
    <node id="1" x="-100.0" y="-100.0" />
    <node id="2" x="-100.0" y="+100.0" />
    <node id="3" x="+100.0" y="+100.0" />
    <node id="4" x="+100.0" y="-100.0" />
    <node id="5" x="+101.0" y="-100.0" />
</nodes>
```

circle.rou.xml:

```
<!-- filename: circle.rou.xml -->
<routes>
    <vType accel="1.0" decel="5.0" id="Car" length="2.0" maxSpeed="30.0" sigma="0.0" />
    <route id="route0" edges="1to2 2to3 3to4 out"/>
    <vehicle depart="10" id="veh0" route="route0" type="Car" />
</routes>
```

circle.settings.xml

```
<!-- filename: circle.settings.xml -->
<viewsettings>
    <viewport y="100" x="100" zoom="100"/>
    <delay value="100"/>
</viewsettings>
```

circle.sumo.cfg

```
<!-- filename: circle.sumo.cfg -->
<configuration>
  <input>
      <net-file value="circle.net.xml"/>
      <route-files value="circle.rou.xml"/>
  </input>
  <time>
      <begin value="0"/>
      <end value="10000"/>
  </time>
</configuration>
```

The net file is a bit long so I wont post it, but it is generated from sumo 0.25 using:

```
netconvert --node-files=circle.nod.xml --edge-files=circle.edg.xml --output-file=circle.net.xml
```

Comment: Could you post your configuration file for SUMO?

Comment: sure, I added them in the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default step length for SUMO is set to 1 second. The error occurs because you set a different step length for your OMNeT++ simulation by setting  `*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s` in your omnetpp.ini file. You need to add step length to your SUMO configuration as well. This can be done by adding `<step-length value="0.1"/>` to the `<time>` element in the XML structure.
The result should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <input>
      <net-file value="circle.net.xml"/>
      <route-files value="circle.rou.xml"/>
  </input>
  <time>
      <begin value="0"/>
      <end value="10000"/>
      <step-length value="0.1"/>
  </time>
</configuration>
```